# Extending the property window in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

XNA Game Studio somehow extended the properties window in Visual Studio with two new combo boxes, "Importer" and "Processor". These combo boxes contained the available importers and processors defined in code in the current solution, and when these fields were changed, the setting was saved to the corresponding item's metadata in the project file.

I'm curious about how they achieved this? Any information would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: [This link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138529.aspx) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a old but good [article](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2008/09/09/extending-visual-studio-properties/) explaining the principles behind how it's done. Basically it comes down to implementing the [`IExtenderProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.iextenderprovider.aspx) interface and determine which objects it should extend via the [`CanExtendMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.iextenderprovider.canextend.aspx), using the CATID of the object to identify it. For the object to be extended you return an extender using the [`GetExtender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.iextenderprovider.getextender.aspx) method. Note that the extender must be marked as [`ComVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx).

The extender provider is [registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.objectextenders.registerextenderprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) either statically in the registry or dynamically using code. The documentation is very thin, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y92k2w2.aspx) says that the extenders are able to add properties and also hide or alter existing properties.